# CMake - libtiff cross-compilation

Tags: cmake, android-ndk, shared-libraries, libtiff

For my Android application, I want to port a C++ code which needs libtiff.

I have downloaded sources of [libtiff](http://www.libtiff.org/) and I try to compile them to generate `libtiff.so` in different architectures :

- arm64-v8a
- armeabi-v7a
- x86
- x86_64

But all I have succeeded in is to generate a `libtiff.dylib`...

What can I do to generate **.so instead of .dylib** in the 4 previous architecture ?

Here are my command lines :

```
> cd libtiff
> mkdir install
> cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install --enable-shared .
> make
> make install
```

Note: I'm on Mac and compilation stuff is not my favorite subject ^^

Comment: Host compiler for MacOS creates binaries for MacOS (e.g. libraries have `.dylib` extension) . For produce binaries for other architectures,  you need to perform **cross-compilation**. Find and install a *cross-compiler*, find [CMake toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) for it (or write the toolchain by hands) and use this toolchain with `-D` option for `cmake`.

Comment: oh ok. Any suggestion for a cross-compiler perhaps ?

Comment: Just google for it. E.g. "macos cross compile x86 cmake".

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I found a solution with cmake & ninja, but I can't post my answer

Comment: Does your solution significantly differ from common cross compiling for Android SDK? E.g. like in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385391/compiling-ffmpeg-for-android-on-mac.

Comment: yes, totally different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to cross-compile this lib with Android tools.

Here are the command lines to generate, for example, the arm64-v8a version

```
> [CMAKE_BIN_PATH]/cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -DANDROID_NDK=[NDK_PATH] -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[NDK_PATH]/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=[CMAKE_BIN_PATH]/ninja -G Ninja
> [CMAKE_BIN_PATH]/ninja
> [CMAKE_BIN_PATH]/ninja install
```

or, in a one-line version

```
> [CMAKE_BIN_PATH]/cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -DANDROID_NDK=[NDK_PATH] -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[NDK_PATH]/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=[CMAKE_BIN_PATH]/ninja -G Ninja && [CMAKE_BIN_PATH]/ninja && [CMAKE_BIN_PATH]/ninja install
```

In details:

- [CMAKE_BIN_PATH] is the path of *cmake*: **/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin**
- [NDK_PATH] is the path of the NDK: **/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle**
- CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is a flag to specify the install dir. In my case, I've decided to create the *install* dir in the *libtiff* dir
- CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE: if a flag to specify the toolchain to use. Use the Android toolchain file **inside the NDK dir**, and not in the cmake dir
- CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is a flag to specify the path of **ninja**, located in the cmake dir
- *-G* is the specify the build system generator, Ninja here